# How to obtain the length of the last word in the string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, character

I have reversed the string and have a for loop to iterate through the reversed string.

I am counting characters and I know I have a logic flaw, but I cannot pinpoint why I am having this issue.

The solution needs to return the **length of the last word** in the string.

My first thought was to iterate through the string backward (I don't know why I decided to create a new string, I should have just iterated through it by decrementing my for loop from the end of the string).

But the logic should be the same from that point for my second for loop.

My logic is basically to try to count characters that aren't whitespace in the last word, and then when the count variable has a value, as well as the next whitespace after the count has counted the characters of the last word.

```
class Solution {
    public int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        int countWhite = 0;
        char ch;
        String reversed = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            reversed += ch;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < reversed.length(); i++) {
            if(!Character.isWhitespace(reversed.charAt(i))) {
                count++;
                if(count > 1 && Character.isWhitespace(reversed.charAt(i)) == true) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: last word  count of a word from reversed String ?

Comment: What constitutes a _word_ for your purposes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe try this,

```
public int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
    
String [] arr = s.trim().split(" ");


return arr[arr.length-1].length();

}
```

Comment: I was trying to fix my logic, but this is 100% a much easier solution obviously. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, if in case you found the answer to be helpful can you please accept the solution.

Comment: @Lando Concise doesn't always mean the most performant. If you need a conciseness, you can do the same with `lastIndexOf(" ")` which will be more efficient. Another drawback of this approach is that it doesn't handle punctuation. If the given string represents a text, it could end with `.`, `?"`, `?!`, `...`, etc. then the result will be the length of the **last word + non-alphabetic symbols** at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to use index of last space and calculate length from it:

```
public int lengthOfLastWord(String string) {
    int whiteSpaceIndex = string.lastIndexOf(" ");
    if (whiteSpaceIndex == -1) {
        return string.length();
    }
    int lastIndex = string.length() - 1;
    return lastIndex - whiteSpaceIndex;
}
```

`String.lastIndexOf()` finds the start index of the last occurence of the specified string. `-1` means the string was not found, in which case we have a single word and length of the entire string is what we need. Otherwise means we have index of the last space and we can calculate last word length using `lastIndexInWord - lastSpaceIndex`.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to achieve that. The most *efficient* approach is to determine the **index** of the *last white space followed by a letter*.

It could be done by iterating over indexes of the given string (*reminder: `String` maintains an array of bytes internally*) or simply by invoking method `lastIndexOf()`.

Keeping in mind that the length of a string that could be encountered at runtime is limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it'll not be a **performance-wise** solution to allocate in memory an **array**, produced as a result of splitting of this lengthy string, when only the *length of a single element* is required.

The code below demonstrates how to address this problem with **Stream IPA** and a usual `for` loop.

The **logic** of the stream:

- Create an `IntStream` that iterates over the indexes of the given string, starting from the last.
- Discard all non-alphabetic symbols at the end of the string with `dropWhile()`.
- Then retain all letters until the first non-alphabetic symbol encountered by using `takeWhile()`.
- Get the count of element in the stream.

**Stream-based solution:**

```
public static int getLastWordLength(String source) {
    return (int) IntStream.iterate(source.length() - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> --i)
            .map(source::charAt)
            .dropWhile(ch -> !Character.isLetter(ch))
            .takeWhile(Character::isLetter)
            .count();
}
```

If your choice is a **loop** there's no need to reverse the string. You can start iteration from the last index, determine the values of the `end` and `start` and return the difference.

*Just in case*, if you need to **reverse a string** that is the most simple and efficient way:

```
new StringBuilder(source).reverse().toString();
```

**Iterative solution:**

```
public static int getLastWordLength(String source) {
    int end = -1; // initialized with illegal index
    int start = 0;
    for (int i = source.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i)) && end == -1) {
            end = i;
        }
        if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i)) && end != -1) {
            start = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return end == -1 ? 0 : end - start;
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getLastWord("Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall  % _ (&)"));
}
```

**output**

```
4   -   last word is "wall"
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as you have mentioned, your reverse string formed is just a copy of your original string. To rectify that,

```
for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            reversed += ch;
        }
```

Secondly, the second if condition is inside your first if condition. That is why, it will never break ( because you are first checking if character is whitespace, if it is, then you are not going inside the if statement, thus your second condition of your inner if loop will never be satisfied).

```
public class HW5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "My name is Mathew";
        int count = lengthOfLastWord(s);
        System.out.println(count);

    }

    public static int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        int countWhite = 0;
        char ch;
        String reversed = "";
        System.out.println("original string is----" + s);
        for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            reversed += ch;
        }
        System.out.println("reversed string is----" + reversed);
        for (int i = 0; i < reversed.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(reversed.charAt(i)))
                count++;
            if (count > 1 && Character.isWhitespace(reversed.charAt(i)) == true) {
                break;
            }

        }
        return count;

    }
}
```

=

```
 and the output is :
    original string is----My name is Mathew
    reversed string is----wehtaM si eman yM
    6
```

Another way to go about is : you use the inbuilt function split which returns an array of string and then return the count of last string in the array.